# I'm trying to write data to excel with python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to write data to excel with python.

```
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Report.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    excel_merged.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Report", index=False)
    writer.save()
```

but after that, when I open excel file and try to edit and save I get the error, I am not able to save file because of sharing violation.

> Your changes could not be saved to 'Report.xlsx' because of a sharing violation. Try saving to a different file.

could you have any suggestions why it doesn't work?

Comment: You can't modify a file that's already opened by another application. Your `writer` is still alive even though you called `save`. Try using `with  pd.ExcelWriter('Report.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:`

Comment: Try the code that panagiotos recommended... it automatically closes the file on exiting the with block.

Comment: Instead of trying code at random, read the docs and try to understand what's going on. I actually started using Python and Pandas 2 months ago too. If you have a dataframe already, use [to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html). The method's docs have several examples. In the simplest case just `df.to_excel(somePath)` will do. You *don't* need to create an explicit writer - unless you want to do something advanced, like storing multiple datasets in different sheets

Comment: Pandas docs are *very* helpful. The `Getting Started` section is short and saved me a *lot* of time too. Using a Jupyter Notebook, printing `df.columns`, `df.describe()`, `df.dtypes` will show you what's going on at each step.

Comment: actually I did read docs but wasn't able to understand much, I don't know much about programing, just started to learn some things.